Запуск lottie анимации при появлении блока в Tilda
У меня есть lottie-анимация, которая загружена в zero-блок в html. Нужно, чтобы она проигрывалась, когда этот блок появляется на экране, сейчас она запускается, как только загружается сайт.
(Все коды взяты из инструкций по добавлению lottie на тильду, сама я в коде разбираюсь посредственно)
Блок где отображается анимация:
<!-- Lottie анимация -->
<div id="lottie-1"></div>

Следующий html-блок
<!-- Этот код загружает библиотеку lottie-web для Lottie анимации-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lottie-web/5.7.5/lottie_light.min.js"></script>

И код, который запускает анимацию:
<script>
    bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById("lottie-1"),
    renderer: "svg",
    loop: false, <!-- Меняй это значение на "true", если хочешь, чтобы анимация повторялась -->
    autoplay: false,
    path: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Didimico/ddb2404eff01e59e7d403a24fbf512e1/raw/5b071c7caa04ad827477fea068a98ba8fd07f547/map2.json"
    });
</script>

Подскажите идеи, как написать это правильно...
